# Azure ASP.NET MVC Role page will not start on IIS7 on Win7 x64

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-7, azure

I try to run a Plain Vanilla ASP.NET MVC web site on my system under Azure, but the page does not start

I have been able to publish the same web page on Windows Vista Ultimate using IIS7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you try to start it?

I would check that all the right IIS features are installed... check this list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573369.aspx

(HTTP redirection would be my guess for the missing feature that impacts MVC.)

Comment: Thanks for the checklist, Steve. You were right, HTTP redirect was missing. Excellent! Just a proposal: Maybe such activations can be included in the Azure SDK installation wizard? So that a poor guy like me would not forget one checkmark.

Comment: I *think* that if you install via the Web Platform Installer it does this.